# Julia - Preallocating for sparse matrices

Tags: memory, memory-management, julia

I was reading about preallocation from [Performance Tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/#Pre-allocating-outputs-1) and it has this example:

```
function xinc!(ret::AbstractVector{T}, x::T) where T
    ret[1] = x
    ret[2] = x+1
    ret[3] = x+2
    nothing
end

function loopinc_prealloc()
    ret = Array{Int}(3)
    y = 0
    for i = 1:10^7
        xinc!(ret, i)
        y += ret[2]
    end
    y
end
```

I see that the example is trying to change `ret` which is preallocated. However, when I tried the following:

```
function addSparse!(sp1, sp2)
    sp1 = 2*sp2
    nothing
end

function loopinc_prealloc()
    sp1 = spzeros(3, 3)
    y = 0
    for i = 1:10^7
        sp2 = sparse([1, 2], [1, 2], [2 * i, 2 * i], 3, 3)
        addSparse!(sp1, sp2)
        y += sp1[1,1]
    end
    y
end
```

I don't think `sp1` is updated by `addSparse!`. In the example from Julia, function `xinc!` modifies `ret` one by one. How can I do the same to a sparse matrix?

In my actual code, I need to update a big sparse matrix in a loop for the sake of saving memory it makes sense for me to preallocate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not that the Matrix is sparse. The issue is that when you use the assignment operator `=` you assign the name `sp1` to a new object (with value `2sp2`), rather than updating the `sp1` matrix. Consider the example from performance tips: `ret[1] = x` does not reassign `ret` it just modifies it's elements.
Use the `.=` operator instead to overwrite all the elements of a container.

Comment: It worked. However, when I do `x .= x + 1`, where `x` is a number, I get a broadcasting error. I suppose that's because `x` is a scalar in this case. What's the equivalent of `.=` for scalars?

Comment: Preallocation isn't relevant for scalars.